# ¿Cómo tomar un valor de un array y salir?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistemas que asigne reportes automáticamente de acuerdo a las personas que estén activas. Las personas que estén activas están almacenadas en un arreglo de objetos.

Lo que estoy tratando de conseguir, es tomar el primer valor, mandarlo a otra variable y a la segunda vuelta tomar el segundo valor, y la tercera vuelta tomar el tercer valor, y continuar así, de acuerdo a cuantos elementos haya en el arreglo. Cuando se llegue al último valor, reiniciar la cuenta y volver a repetir el mismo proceso.

`let ids = [ {id:7551}, {id:28}, {id:3231} ];`

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con reiniciar la cuenta y volver a repetir

Comment: Estoy tratando de recorrer el arreglo, para tomar el valor de id, tomando en cuenta que esté en un ciclo, y este arreglo tiene 3 elementos, una vez que llegue al tercero volver a iniciar las iteraciones.

Comment: Un ciclo infinito?

Comment: y cuando terminarian las iteraciones?

Comment: en la pregunta dices "tomar un array y salir" y en la descripcion dices "tomar un valor y volver a repetir el mismo proceso"... al fin que es lo que quieres? que has intentado?

Comment: Aquí suponiendo diría que ese arreglo de IDs cambiaria con nuevos IDs o sea nuevos usuario conectados y que en otro array se vayan pusheando todos esos IDs al final haciendo una lista de los usuarios que estuvieron conectados, no se.

Comment: Necesitas agregar más información estamos perdidos perdidos perdidos